# Scrollbar on the text area inside powerpoint slide

Tags: powerpoint

I want to add a scroll bar inside a ppt slide. I have microsoft office 2007. I have searched and got that i have to add activex controls. Can someone provide full information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After alot of searching i finally got that there is nothing like scroll bar in Presentation. I have finally used animations only to give that effect.

Comment: To animate the vertical scrolling of text, I used the Morph transition (available to PowerPoint 2016 users who have an Office 365 subscription). For example, if I have a text box that is taller than the slide, I create one slide showing the top of the text, then I duplicate that slide, move the text box up on the duplicate slide so that the last line of text is visible, and then I apply a Morph transition between the two slides.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, see this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-NAxBN3PWM&t=12m25s) that I exported from PowerPoint.

Answer (score 2):

In Office 2007 to add the ActiveX Control Toolbox  follow the below steps:
 1. Go to File -> Options
 2. Select Customize Ribbon
 3. Choose All Commands in Choose Commands From Drop Down
 4. Add 'Controls' And 'Control Properties' and save

Now you will be able to see two new options in the ribbon,
Click on Control -> Select Text Box
Draw the text box on slide,

Select this text box and click on Control Properties

Change Multiline to True and ScrollBar to Your Desired value.

You will be able to do what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a text box control with scroll bars enabled as mentioned by Kris Selbekk or a stand-alone scroll bar control. Both are found in the Developer tab which is not visible by default. You can enable the tab in PowerPoint options, see the how to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ispringsolutions.com/articles/add-scroll-text-to-powerpoint.html

this works beautifully, along with making your presentation web-ready. but it does require third-party software.

(edit: thank you for the instructive comments, folks. here's a little more info about the procedure.)

first, you simply write your desired text in MS Word and apply a color scheme which matches your PPT slide. then, you save the document: **File → Save → Web Page, Filtered**

once you have your HTML file prepared, you can use the 3rd-party PowerPoint add-in. iSpring Pro is the most affordable option which will offer this solution. after you install it, a new tab will appear on your PowerPoint toolbar/ribbon. click the **iSpring Pro** tab and then click **Web Object**. the drop-down on the upper left will offer two options, "Web address" and "Local path": select **Local path** and then just paste the path to the HTML file which you just saved. make sure **Display in slide** is checked, click OK, and then the object placeholder will appear on your slide. adjust the size to your specs. if it's a lot of text, the scrollbar will automatically appear after you publish. you can click **Preview** on the iSpring Pro ribbon to see the results. When you're ready to publish, click **Publish**. i suggest **Combined(Flash+HTML5)** for greatest quality/compatibility.

(side note: obviously, the ability to add web objects to PPT slides extends far beyond mere scrollable textboxes. i invite you to experiment with various local and web-based resources!)

Answer (score 0):

I found this at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-powerpoint/can-i-insert-a-scrolling-text-box-that-is-manually/fcece4ff-b340-46dd-a3fe-0c11e08605b1.

> View - Toolbars - Control Toolbox - click on Text box button. Drag with your mouse the size box you want.
>
> Click on the properties button, click on MultiLine and choose true.
>
> Click on EnterKey behaviour, change to true.
>
> Click on Scrollbars and change accordingly, if you want both horizontal and vertical scrollbars choose 3.
>
> Close the properties window.
>
> Start your show click in the textbox and type or even paste your text in. If the text exceeds the height you have put in scrollbars will appear.

Don't know if it works because it appears to be PC-only and I'm a Mac user. However, anyone interested might try it and let the original poster know.